# Why do I have to click TextField twice in order for my list to display?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I updated from @material-ui/core@v4.9.1 to @material-ui/core@v4.11.0. Since doing so All of my TextFields have to be clicked twice in order for the lists to display. The issue doesn't seem to be related to the update in version because if switch back to the v4.9.1 version the problem persists.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.10.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.1",
```

.js file

```
    let getBoards = () => {
    const client = new GraphQLClient(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })

    const query = `{
        boards() {
            id
            name
            owner {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }`

    client.request(query)
      .then(data => {
        console.log('data: ', data)
        let tempArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < data.boards.length; i++) {
          if (data.boards[i].name.indexOf('INT') > -1) {
            tempArray.push({
              id: data.boards[i].id,
              name: data.boards[i].name
            })
          }
        }

        let compare = (a, b) => {
          // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
          const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
          const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();

          let comparison = 0;
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else if (nameA < nameB) {
            comparison = -1;
          }
          return comparison;
        }

        setBoards(tempArray.sort(compare));
      })
  }

    <TextField
      required
      error={state.typeErrorBoard}
      select
      label="Select board"
      className={props.classes.textField}
      variant="filled"
      value={state.BoardName}
      onClick={getBoards}
      onChange={e => handleBoardChange(e)}
      margin="dense"
    >
      {boards.map((board, index) =>
        <MenuItem
          key={index}
          value={board.name}
        >
          {board.name}
        </MenuItem>
      )}
    </TextField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide the [select prop for the Textfield](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/), you are basically rendering a `select` not the Textfield.

see the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js)

```js
...
   {select ? (
        <Select
          aria-describedby={helperTextId}
          id={id}
          labelId={inputLabelId}
          value={value}
          input={InputElement}
          {...SelectProps}
        >
          {children}
        </Select>
      ) : (
        InputElement
      )}
...
```

- With the above, the Textfield's onClick (getBoards) is bound to the select's root div (not to the Textfield). The select's root div is rendered when you focus on Textfield. Inspect element and take a look.
- So, when you click on the Textfield for the 1st time, the `select` is just rendered (takes up the entire screen) and hence `getBoards` is not executed.
- But when you click 2nd time, on the input (or anywhere on the screen), `getBoards` function is called because select is now in the dom and so is the onClick handler(getBoards).
- you can check by printing `e.target` (where event is originally attached) and `e.currentTarget` (from where event is fired) in the `getBoards` function

To make it work with single click, you can do any of the following:

- use a useEffect and call `getBoards`
- use onFocus instead of onClick

[See demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x6sri?file=/demo.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function MultilineTextFields(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [boards, setBoards] = React.useState([]);

  let getBoards = e => {
    console.log("e", e.target);
    console.log("e cur", e.currentTarget);
    e.stopPropagation();
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log("boards", res);
        setBoards(res);
      });
  };

  // useEffect(() => getBoards(), []);  //<----another solution

  return (
    // <div onClick={getBoards}> //<----another solution (don't click on text-input , click on the padding)
    <div>
      <TextField
        required
        // error={state.typeErrorBoard}
        select
        label="Select board"
        className={classes.root}
        variant="filled"
        value={""}
        onClick={getBoards}
        // onFocus={getBoards}  //<----another solution
        // onChange={e => handleBoardChange(e)}
        margin="dense"
      >
        {boards &&
          boards.map((board, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={board.username}>
              {board.username}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </TextField>
    </div>
  );
}
```